# How to convert this line from Velocity to FreeMarker?

Tags: java, velocity, freemarker

I want to convert this line from Velocity to Freemarker:

```
#set ($valid_portlet_description = $validator.isNotNull($portlet_description) 
&& $portlet_description.indexOf('javax.portlet.description') == -1)
```

I tried to change the code to:

```
<#assign valid_portlet_description = validator.isNotNull(portlet_description) 
&& portlet_description?index_of("javax.portlet.description") == "-1" />
```

But I get this following error:

> `freemarker.template.TemplateException`: The only legal comparisons are
>   between two numbers, two strings, or two dates. Left  hand operand is
>   a `freemarker.template.SimpleNumber` Right hand operand is a
>   `freemarker.template.SimpleScalar`

Comment: Note that you should update FreeMarker. 2.3.23 gives much more understandable error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message complains about this statement:

```
portlet_description?index_of("javax.portlet.description") == "-1"
```

It says that you have different types: the number on the left, but `SimpleScalar` (which is just `String` in Freemarker terms) on the right. To fix this you should just remove quotes:

```
portlet_description?index_of("javax.portlet.description") == -1
```